# Azure Data Factory Dataset Dynamic Folder Path

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data set that resides under a folder path where the date is dynamic (e.g. rootfolder/subfolder/yyyy/mm/dd/subfolder/subfolder), and I am trying to pull it with a copy activity. So far I cannot get Data Factory to recognize that my date is dynamic...

This is the code that I have tried so far:

```
["rootfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfoler/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')}/subfolder/file"]
```

Comment: Note the `@` symbol is for the start of the expression only, you don't need to repeat it throughout the expression.   The curly braces `{` are for what's called string interpolation, basically when you want to embed this expression within a string.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714497/in-adf-v2-how-to-append-date-yyyymmdd-to-filename-dynamically-for-s3-data) for a similar answer recently.

Comment: This can work if you try ```.../subfoler/{Year}/{Month}{Day}/subfolder/file```.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of concat function provided by data factory.

```
@concat('rootfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'),'/subfolder/file')
```

The concat function is similar as in programming languages which concats the strings.

More details: [Azure Data Factory Loop Through Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535449/4111181)

Answer (score 1):

Just to build pm Anish K answer you can also shorten this a bit by using formatting

```
formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

So final answer would be

```
@concat('rootfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy//MM/dd'),'/subfolder/file')
```

In case you want to learn a bit more on parametrization on ADF feel free to check out this video https://youtu.be/pISBgwrdxPM